# How to convert Oracle stored procedure to MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle, stored-procedures, converters

I did these SQL statements in oracle

```
create or replace procedure teacherlist(lists out SYS_REFCURSOR )
is 
begin
open lists for 
select teacherid,teachername,status,email,contact,address
from teacher;
end;
```

but now I have to do the same stored procedure in MySQL for PHPMyAdmin, which I did it like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `teacherlist`(OUT `v_stuid` VARCHAR(10), OUT `v_teachername` VARCHAR(100), OUT `v_status` VARCHAR(20), OUT `v_email` VARCHAR(40), OUT `v_contact` VARCHAR(20), OUT `v_address` VARCHAR(100))
begin
DECLARE v_teacherid varchar(10);
DECLARE v_teachername varchar(100);
DECLARE v_status varchar(20);
DECLARE v_email varchar(40);
DECLARE v_contact varchar(20);
DECLARE v_address varchar(100);
DECLARE My_Cursor CURSOR FOR 
select teacherid,teachername,status,email,contact,address
from teacher;
OPEN My_Cursor;
FETCH My_Cursor INTO v_teacherid,v_teachername,v_status,v_email,v_contact,v_address;
CLOSE My_Cursor;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

which I'm not sure right or wrong because when I execute the procedure it did not give me any output.

Comment: Don't use the same name for parameters and declared variables.(backticking does not make them different..)

Comment: Not being ORACLE what is this supposed to do?

Comment: @P.Salmon: see https://community.oracle.com/thread/888365

Comment: @P.Salmon it was supposed to fetch the data from the table teacher and display the output, but I'm not really sure about this as I'm still learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent of Oracle Database REF CURSOR in MySQL.

The easiest solution is probably something like:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE  PROCEDURE teacherlist()
BEGIN
select teacherid,teachername,status,email,contact,address
from teacher;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And using `call` statement to use the result set.

Comment: it works, thank you so much. maybe I didn't really understand how to use the cursor properly so i just follow it bluntly when i saw cursor in MySQL coding in others people question.